# Feasability of melting through ice crust with radiocative heater

Tags: thermodynamics, aerospace-engineering

I'm pretty interested in space exploration. Here I'm interested in a moon of Jupiter (Encealadus) which is covered by a thick ice crust, but apparently has at some depth a liquid water ocean which contains interesting molecules/salts/etc. Therefore has been some talks about how/if a probe could be sent there to investigate whether there might be life in that ocean. The most obvious way would seem to melt your way through the ice crust.

So I've decided to try to make a napkin calculation about the feasibility of this idea, from an energy perspective. I'd be curious to know if you see wholes in that reasoning, if some constants are wrong, etc. It's a napkin calculation - I just wrote it down & calculated mentally. So obviously not meant to be an accurate answer, most about a ballpark estimate. It's rounded to whatever integer makes calculations easier to do with just pencil/paper.

### **Energy needed to melt the ice**

- We assume @ stp (probably not right), use common values for water (there are salts in it so probably not right)
- To estimate that, we must know the mass of ice to be melted.
- To get the mass of ice, we need the volume of ice our probe would displace

### Volume & mass of ice

Assuming a radius of 1m for our probe for 1km of ice crust. This is essentially a huge cylinder, so V = d*(2pi*r²), where d = thickness of crust (1km) and r = radius of our probe (1m). You get:
 - V = pi*10⁴ m³ 
 - density of ice = 10³kg/m³

With that, we can get the mass of ice to melt:
 - pi*10^7 kg of ice to melt through

Consider specific heat for ice of ~2kJ/kg, it seems we would need:

~10^8 kJ to melt all that ice.

### Energy available from radioactive source

For P-239, I found ~200 meV as value for energy of a [fission event](http://www.world-nuclear.org/information-library/nuclear-fuel-cycle/introduction/physics-of-nuclear-energy.aspx).
Molar mass = 239*10⁻² kg/moles or ~50 moles/kg
Avocadro number ~6*10²³ atomes/mole

Let's say we bring 1kg. P-239 has as half-life of ~24 000 years or 600*10³ months. We'll use the half-life to calculate a rate of energy emitted per month, which we can then compare to the energy needed to melt the ice to see if have any chances of melting through it in a reasonable amount of time.

So, taking avocadro's number with the molar mass & considering 1kg of P239 we have ~4*10¹¹kJ of energy. Since we're using the half-life to get a rate of emission, we need to divide that by two (e.g. only half the Pu decays during the half-life).

We find that we emit ~10⁶kJ/month/kg of Pu we bring.

### Conclusion

It seems we would need quite a few months to melt through just 1km of ice.

### Questions

- What might be wrong about that calculations, implicit assumptions that may not be right, etc.
- What other considerations we omitted that may have significant impact? E.g. our probe might be much smaller, will also have things other than Pu (affects heat dissipations?), etc.

Comment: What temperature did you assume for the ice? 0 deg C or -10 deg C or -20 or -30? Or colder?

Comment: Assuming standard temperature & pressures. As said probably not right, but I'm not really sure where to find tables for properties about theses things.

They may or not vary much - but then I'm kind of hoping people here will be able to tell if that's the case!

Comment: What temperature do you intend the melt water to be & how do you intend to deal with the possibility of the melt water refreezing & closing off the hole, particularly near the surface when the drill/probe is deep?